# Design Slackbot service to send automated messages

Tags: slack, slack-api

It is my very first time to write a slack bot and i am wondering how to design it.

The bot supposed to be available and respond to end-users' messages immediately.

The thing is that I need that the bot will also send schedules messages to registered users with automation results.

Use case example:

> A user sends a message to the bot and registered to a service that
>   will check for changes in X. On a specific interval, my backend will
>   call an automation that checks for those changes and will send a
>   message to the user with the results.

What will be the best practice for this scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a basic outline.

**1. Basic setup**

- Slack app with bot user
- Database
- Scheduler (e.g. local CRON service, or web-cron like [cron-job.org](https://cron-job.org/en/))

**2. Registration**

- Use [Events API](https://api.slack.com/events-api) to listen to messages from users send via mention ([`app_mention`](https://api.slack.com/events/app_mention)) or direct message ([`message.im`](https://api.slack.com/events/message.im))
- You app needs to store the received "registration" from each user in a database
- Respond to user request directly if needed with [`chat.postMessage`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage)

**3. Scheduled response**

- Scheduler calls your app
- Your app check if responses are due with a database query
- If yes: App sends responses to users via [`chat.postMessage`](https://api.slack.com/methods/chat.postMessage) (but not more than one message per sec due to rate limiting)